# Hive : How to perform JOIN Operation with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have two tables

```
A -- > id , name
B -- > id , value
```

In B table, I have multiple duplicate id, I want to find average of particular id and print id , name , AVG(value)

Here is my query for finding average in table B

```
SELECT id, AVG(value) FROM B GROUP BY id;
```

I need to perform JOIN operation, How to perform JOIN Operation with GROUP BY.

Comment: does the `id` on both the tables represent the same ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you want: you want to group by both the `id` and the `name`

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, avg(b.value)
FROM A
     JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
GROUP BY A.id, A.name
```